# Replicating nuxt/content functionality in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify-cms, nuxtjs3, nuxt-content

I'm experimenting with Nuxt 3, Netlify and Netlify CMS. I'm familiar with vue but new to Nuxt.

I'm aware that nuxt/content is [not yet compatible with Nuxt 3](https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/974). Without nuxt/content, what would be the best way to load all the files that Netlify CMS is creating in /content and supply them to my vue components?

So far I've tried creating some server/middleware, which collects the content using node JS fs module but I'm unsure how best to supply it to the app. Or perhaps I could write a server-side plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nuxt Content v2 has been released](https://content.nuxtjs.org/blog/announcing-v2), and it should have the support of Nuxt 3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Nuxt Content v2, as pointed out by @Yuki Inoue, does work with Nuxt 3. Here's a proof of concept => https://gitlab.com/k16e/cfood

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).